# Hide and show for cloned divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide and show cloned divs. The following code works fine but the Radio button group (orginal) gets unselected when I click on the cloned Radio button Group. I renamed all the radio buttons and DIVs to "_1", "_2" etc after cloning. Please let me know if there are any suggestions. Here is my code.

```
$(function() 
{     
    $('input:radio').live('click', function () {
        var value = $(this).attr('id').substring(10); 
        if ($(this).val() === '1') 
        {       
            $("#div1Wrap_" + value).show();
            $("#div2Wrap_" + value).hide();
        }  
        else if ($(this).val() === '2') 
        {
            $("#div1Wrap_" + value).hide();
            $("#div2Wrap_" + value).show();
        }  
    });
});
```

Comment: are you changing group for cloned radio buttons? will you show us cloning part?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the js on those radio buttons is also being copied over in the clone (which is the default in clone()) which effectively links the state of the two copies.  If you don't want that then you need to do clone(false).

Comment: I did change it to clone(false). But still it does the same thing.

Comment: I just checked with FireFox browser. It works fine. I think it looks like IE7 issue.